# Hibernate search with ResultTransformer (DTO)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-search

I need to collect a specific DTO from the Hibernate search results, I connected all the dependencies in the maven, wrote the following request based on the official documentation (I deleted the unnecessary code, which can only confuse, left only what is needed for the search):

```
public List<QuestionDto> search(String text) {

    FullTextQuery query = fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(queryBuilder
            .simpleQueryString()
            .onField("description")
            .matching(text)
            .createQuery())
            .setProjection("id", "description", "title", "countValuable", "persistDateTime", "user.fullName", "tags")
            .setResultTransformer(new ResultTransformer() {

                @Override
                public Object transformTuple(Object[] tuple, String[] aliases) {
                    return QuestionDto.builder()
                            .id(((Number) tuple[0]).longValue())
                            .title((String) tuple[2])
                            .description((String) tuple[1])
                            .countValuable(((Number) tuple[3]).intValue())
                            .persistDateTime((LocalDateTime) tuple[4])
                            .username((String) tuple[5])
                            .tags((List<TagDto>) tuple[6])
                            .build();
                }

                @Override
                public List transformList(List collection) {
                    return collection;
                }
            });
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

**BUT for some reason instead of tags comes NULL**
May be someone have any idea?

Entity Question

```
@Indexed
public class Question {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Field(store = Store.YES)
private String title;

private Integer viewCount = 0;

@Field(store = Store.YES)
private String description;

@Field(store = Store.YES)
private LocalDateTime persistDateTime;

@Field(store = Store.YES)
private Integer countValuable = 0;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
@IndexedEmbedded(includePaths = "fullName")
private User user;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@IndexedEmbedded(includeEmbeddedObjectId = true, includePaths = {"name", "description"})
private List<Tag> tags;
```

Entity Tag

```
public class Tag {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Field(store = Store.YES)
private String name;

@Field(store = Store.YES)
private String description;
private LocalDateTime persistDateTime;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tags", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@ContainedIn
private List<Question> questions;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems here:

1. Projections on multi-valued fields are not supported.
2. You are trying to project on an "object" field: "tags" does not hold a value by itself, it just has sub-fields ("tags.name", "tags.description"). Projections on "object" fields is not supported at the moment.

If you're using the Elasticsearch backend, you can take advantage of the `_source` projection (`org.hibernate.search.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchProjectionConstants#SOURCE`), which will return the string representation of the Elasticsearch document, formatted as JSON. You can then parse it (with Gson, for example) to extract whatever information you need.

And of course, you always have the option of not using projections at all, then extracting the information from the entities loaded from the database.

Note that in Hibernate Search 6 (currently in Beta), we're going to add built-in support for [projections on multi-valued fields](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-3391), but it's unlikely to be added to Hibernate Search 5, which is in maintenance mode (no new features or improvements, only bugfixes).

In a more distant future, we will probably add [more direct support for DTOs](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-3927).